# Adding google maps to my website

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a page and im trying to add google map to it but it doesn't appear in the page, it has no errors in the console log but it doesn't appear in my page, here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyD19cqU2rIzBHOPL_t8GhJJ9cmi-HNpULg"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
        <script>
            function initialize() {
              var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 15,
                scrollwheel: false,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng((31.993072, 35.862211))
              };

              var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googleMap'),
                  mapOptions);


              var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: map.getCenter(),
                animation:google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE,
                icon: 'img/map-marker.png',
                map: map
              });

            }

            google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
        </script>
```

Comment: From what I remember, you have to set the height of the `<div>` explicitly in order for the maps element to show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do with following

1. add callback in src `<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyD19cqU2rIzBHOPL_t8GhJJ9cmi-HNpULg&callback=initialize"></script>`
2. `center:new google.maps.LatLng(31.993072, 35.862211)` instead of `center: new google.maps.LatLng((31.993072, 35.862211))` remove extra round bracket

```js
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 15,
    scrollwheel: false,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(31.993072, 35.862211)
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googleMap'),
    mapOptions);


  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: map.getCenter(),
    animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE,
    //icon: 'img/map-marker.png',
    map: map
  });
}
```

```css
#googleMap {
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyD19cqU2rIzBHOPL_t8GhJJ9cmi-HNpULg&callback=initialize"></script>
<div id="googleMap">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note that the particular key for google map only works for the specific domain, so if you are running on localhost, it won't display a map normally.

Answer (score -1):

Use iframe to show map in your website:

```
<iframe  width="600"  height="450"  frameborder="0" style="border:0"  src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=YOUR_API_KEY
&q=Space+Needle,Seattle+WA" allowfullscreen>
```

[Google Maps Embed API Link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide)